# OpenAPI empty array/object query parameter serializing

Tags: parameters, openapi

Based on the [`allowEmptyValue`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#parameter-object) option I see a lot of old discussions about how empty strings are serialized. However I couldn't find any info about how to handle empty arrays and objects (objects with no required properties) in query parameters.

Let's assume I have the following 2 parameter definitions:

```yaml
paths:
  "/test":
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: possiblyEmptyArray
        style: form
        in: query
        explode: true
        required: true
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: number
      - name: possiblyEmptyObject
        style: form
        in: query
        explode: true
        required: true
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            a:
              type: number
            b:
              type: string
            c:
              type: boolean
```

If this was just JSON, based on their schema for both of these an empty array / object would be acceptable:

- `possiblyEmptyArray` - both `[]` and `[1,2,3]` is ok
- `possiblyEmptyObject` - all of `{}`, `{"a": 1}`, `{"a": 1, b: "hi"}` and `{"a": 1, b: "hi", c: true}` is ok

But in terms of query parameter serialization (and the `explode: true`) option this means **empty query strings**.

What's equally interesting, is that with the `explode: false` option we'd get query strings as such:

- `?possiblyEmptyArray=` - empty value, so nothing after `=`
- `?possiblyEmptyObject=` - empty value, so nothing after `=`

**My question:**

- Is empty arrays/objects like this acceptable for exploded required array/object query parameters (so they simply just don't appear in the query string when empty)?
- Is this ok with non-exploded query parameters? If so, what is the proper serialization?
- Does `allowEmptyValue` option have any effect on this? I see usage is discouraged in the docs, so I'm not sure what to think about it.